# Sum up multiple rows and columns value

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA2Si.png)

Like the input section shows, I have some projects' resource loading. Each project has multiple rows. Each week's resource loading is a column.

I would like to output a list of projects(each project needs to be in a row) of their quarterly resource loading(column).

Please refer the picture for a better understanding.

Things I ve tried but don't work well:

1. Pivot table:

Pivot table can help to address the problem quickly but since I have calculations based on the output, pivot table is not stable enough to be embedded into fomulas for calculation

2. SUMIF(Excel formula or VBA)

I have more than 3000 rows data in input sheet with 100+ projects. Sumif would go through those 3000 rows for each program(that's 300k rows for each column). It works but very ineffecient.

Please let me know for questions

Comment: Are you looking for a faster Sumif function? I suppose you could write a custom sumif function in VBA which stores the 300,000 rows as a 2D array and loop through that. Should be faster than the alternative.

Comment: I would create a vba macro. Have you done vba before?

Comment: @HMVBA Thank you for idea. Yes I am trying to store them in a range and will see how that works

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Yes I am trying with macros. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I worked on to do what you require.  It will look in the `rngColToSearch` range which should simply be the column of data that holds your Program# names. The `rngDataContents` range is used to specify where you have numbers for the summation.  The `rngOutput` is a cell where you want the output to start to be written to.

It will then find and group the rows that contain unique Program #'s. Then, the data for each quarter (week1 through week13, week14 through week26, etc.) will be summed up based on Program#.

Finally, it will output the data starting from a specified region.

The code is as follows (put in a module):

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Type udtMatches
        Name As String
        RowNums() As Integer
        Quarters() As Double  '0 to 3
    End Type

    Private uItems() As udtMatches

    Sub RunIT()
        mySumIF Range("A5:A27"), Range("B5:N27"), Range("G30")
    End Sub

    Public Sub mySumIF(rngColToSearch As Range, rngDataContents As Range, rngOutput As Range)
        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim intJ As Integer
        Dim intK As Integer
        Dim intL As Integer
        Dim strColValues() As String
        Dim intInMaxCol As Integer
        Dim intStartRow As Integer
        Dim intRows As Integer
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strCheck As String
        Dim blnFoundRow As Boolean
        Dim blnFoundName As Boolean
        Dim dblSumCols As Double
        Dim intRow As Integer
        Dim intCol As Integer

        Dim intNameCnt As Integer
        Dim intRowCnt() As Integer

        intRows = rngColToSearch.Rows.Count


        If intRows <> rngDataContents.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "Error: You need to select the Searching Column and the Data Contents such that" & vbCrLf & _
                   "  they have the same row count.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Bad Selection"
        Else
            'Dimension the UDT's
            ReDim uItems(0 To (intRows - 1))
            ReDim intRowCnt(0 To (intRows - 1))
            For intI = 0 To (intRows - 1)
                ReDim uItems(intI).RowNums(0 To (intRows - 1))
            Next intI

            intNameCnt = 0
            'We are good, continue
            For intI = 1 To intRows
                strTemp = LCase(Trim(rngColToSearch.Cells(intI, 1).Value))
                If intI = 1 Then
                    uItems(intNameCnt).Name = Trim(rngColToSearch.Cells(intI, 1).Value)
                    uItems(intNameCnt).RowNums(intRowCnt(intNameCnt)) = intI

                    intRowCnt(intNameCnt) = intRowCnt(intNameCnt) + 1
                    intNameCnt = intNameCnt + 1
                Else
                    blnFoundName = False
                    For intJ = 0 To (intNameCnt - 1)
                        strCheck = LCase(Trim(uItems(intJ).Name))
                        If strCheck = strTemp Then
                            blnFoundName = True
                            'Name is found, now search for Rownumber
                            blnFoundRow = False
                            For intK = 0 To (intRowCnt(intJ) - 1)
                                If uItems(intJ).RowNums(intK) = intI Then
                                    blnFoundRow = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next intK
                            If Not blnFoundRow Then
                                'Add it to the list
                                uItems(intJ).RowNums(intRowCnt(intJ)) = intI

                                intRowCnt(intJ) = intRowCnt(intJ) + 1
                            End If
                        End If

                        If blnFoundRow Then Exit For
                    Next intJ

                    If Not blnFoundName Then
                        'Add it to the list
                        uItems(intNameCnt).Name = rngColToSearch.Cells(intI, 1).Value
                        uItems(intNameCnt).RowNums(intRowCnt(intNameCnt)) = intI

                        intRowCnt(intNameCnt) = intRowCnt(intNameCnt) + 1
                        intNameCnt = intNameCnt + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next intI

            ReDim Preserve uItems(0 To (intNameCnt - 1))
            'Now, redim the udt's
            For intI = 0 To (intNameCnt - 1)
                ReDim Preserve uItems(intI).RowNums(0 To intRowCnt(intI) - 1)
                ReDim Preserve uItems(intI).Quarters(0 To 3)
            Next intI


            'Now, for each 13 weeks we need to add the columns 
            'intI = Quarters
            For intI = 0 To (intNameCnt - 1)

                For intK = 0 To 3
                'intJ = Weeks of Quarters
                    dblSumCols = 0
                    For intJ = 0 To (intRowCnt(intI) - 1)
                        For intL = 1 To 13
                            With rngDataContents
                                dblSumCols = dblSumCols + 
                                             CDbl(.Cells(uItems(intI).RowNums(intJ),
                                                   (intK * 13 + intL)).Value)
                            End With
                        Next intL
                    Next intJ
                    uItems(intI).Quarters(intK) = dblSumCols
                Next intK
            Next intI


            'Set up the Column and Row Labels
            intRow = 2
            intCol = 1
            For intI = 0 To (intNameCnt - 1)
                rngOutput.Cells(intRow + intI, intCol).Value = uItems(intI).Name
            Next intI
            intRow = 1
            intCol = 2
            For intI = 0 To 3
                rngOutput.Cells(intRow, intI + intCol).Value = "Q" & (intI + 1)
            Next intI


            'And finally print out the data.
            intRow = 2
            For intI = 0 To (intNameCnt - 1)
                For intJ = 0 To 3
                    rngOutput.Cells(intRow + intI, intJ + intCol).Value = 
                        uItems(intI).Quarters(intJ)
                Next intJ
            Next intI

        End If

    End Sub
```